# Install and activate plugins across 200 wordpress installations via SSH

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-supercache

I have an ubuntu server where I have roughly 200 wordpress websites running. I noticed the server is at it's limits (mysql/cpu) and almost non of my websites have WP Super Cache installed.

Logging into 200 websites and installing WP Super Cache manually would take forever.

Is there a way I can install and activate WP super cache via SSH (I have root access) across all of my wordpress installations?

All my websites are on the server in this structure

/srv/users/domain1com/apps/domain1com/public/
/srv/users/domain2com/apps/domain2com/public/
/srv/users/domain3com/apps/domain3com/public/